# Symfony2 - doctrine:schema:update fails with entity outside of a bundle ( decoupled )

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I was reading this article:

http://danielribeiro.org/yes-you-can-have-low-coupling-in-a-symfony-standard-edition-application/

The author mentioned that it's possible to have this kind of artitcture for the project:

```
src/
└── Vendor/
    └── Product/
        └── Bundle
            └── BlogBundle/
            └── ForumBundle/
            └── SiteBundle/
                └── Controller/
                    └── IndexController.php
                └── Resources/
                    └── views/
                        └── index.html.twig
                └── ProductSiteBundle.php
        └── Entity
            └── User.php
        └── Repository
            └── UserRepository.php
        └── Service
            └── UserPasswordRetrievalService.php
```

so i followed the article and end up with something like this:

```
src/
└── Product/
    └── Bundle
        └── SiteBundle/
            └── Controller/
                └── IndexController.php
            └── Resources/
                └── views/
                    └── index.html.twig
            └── ProductSiteBundle.php
    └── Entity
        └── User.php
```

Now Symfony can't see my User.php the author didn't mention if i have to add any extra code to make this works, and now i'm getting this error:

```
MappingException: The class 'Product\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces OtherNameSpaces
```

**UPDATE**

So i deleted my existing code. and Did something like this:

```
src/
└── Product/
    └── Bundle
        └── SiteBundle/
            └── Controller/
                └── IndexController.php
            └── Resources/
                └── views/
                    └── index.html.twig
            └── ProductSiteBundle.php
    └── Entity
        └── User.php
```

User.php

```
namespace Product\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
}
```

and then

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force //No Metadata Classes to process.
```

it seems Symfony is not aware of that folder at all. is there any place where i can ask symfony to look inside that folder ?

Comment: What is your namespace in User.php ?

Comment: `namespace Product\Entity` @Tib

Comment: @nifr answer is right on top of it. My article, where you first heard of this practice, does not explain (on purpose) how you do it internally.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro loved your article - we should definitely raise more awareness for good application design. keep up the good work! :)

Comment: @DanielRibeiro Great article indeed! thanks for checking my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [good blog article](http://www.zalas.eu/how-to-store-doctrine-entities-outside-of-a-symfony-bundle) by Jakub Zalas describes how to map entities that live outside of bundles.

You need to manually add where doctrine shall look for mapping information as shown below.

This makes the mapping information available to the `doctrine:schema:update` command aswell. Don't forget to clear your cache after the configuration change.

```
# app/config/config.php
doctrine:
    orm:
        # ...
        mappings:
            Acme:
                type: annotation
                is_bundle: false
                dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/Entity
                prefix: Acme\Entity
                alias: Acme
```

You can now access the repository like this (because of the alias definition):

```
$entityManager->getRepository('Acme:YourEntity');
```